Functional calculus on the Schwartz space instead of $L^2$?
As far as I know, functional calculus is typically carried out on Hilbert spaces with (possibly unbounded) self-adjoint operators.
However, I wonder if there is a way to do it on the space of test functions like the Schwartz space.
For example, I remember that $T:=i \frac{d}{dx}$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Thus, we can make sense of the expression $f(T)$ for $f(x):= e^{-x^2}$.
However, $T$ is a "continuous" linear operator on the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.
My question is:

Is there a rigorous way of making sense of $f(T)$ as a continuous linear operator on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$?

I have not been able to find any relevant reference on such topics. Could anyone please help me?

This is pretty well what the Fourier transform was designed to deal with.  It is an isometric isomorphism of $L^2$ which diagonalises your operator and leaves the Schwartz space invariant.   Thus $f(T)$ is an unbounded operator on the former which maps the latter space continuously into itself whenever $f$ is a polynomial. With a little analysis this can be extended to more general smooth functions which  satisfy suitable growth conditions

I am curious how you extend to some general smooth functions. For example, is it by Taylor expansion with respect to $T$? How do we make sense of convergence in that case?

Also, I used a very specific example of $T = i \frac{d}{dx}$, but I also hope to figure out how it would be like for a general (unbounded) self-adjoint $T$ on $L^2$ which is continuous on the Frechet topology of $\mathcal{S}$.

Of course, $A=L(\mathscr S,\mathscr S)$ is an algebra so that one can apply polynomials to its elements. However, the continuity of $T\in A$ is somewhat involved: If $|\cdot|_n$ denote the usual seminorms of $\mathscr S$, it means that, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there are $m=m(n)\in\mathbb N$ and $c=c(n)\ge 0$ with $|T(x)|n\le c|x|{m(n)}$. The continuity estimates for the powers $T^r$ thus involve compositions $m\circ\cdots\circ m$ with $r$-factors -- I doubt that just a little analysis will tell you which estimates of the Taylor coefficients of an entire function $f$ ...tbc

... will yield convergence of the corresponding series in $A$, all the more since the natural topology of $A$ as a projective limit of locally convex inductive limits is not easy to deal with.

@JochenWengenroth I didn't realize that you put your comments here already! It does seem nontrivial to establish functional calculus on $\mathscr{S}$..
